# Is it possible using SEDE to find list of users with specific SE attributes?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I came across [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), which is so awesome, to begin with!

Is it possible to search for users having specific SE attributes?

For instance, I want to find user(s) in English Language and Usage with most number of `Great Answer` badge.

(or)

Question and Answer with the highest scores respectively in The Workplace SE.

I am sorry if my examples are naive. I just want to know the possibilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sure, those kinds of queries are possible.  You can write SEDE queries right on the site (click on "compose query") in SQL.  That page shows you what tables are available and what columns they have.  Usually you'll need to JOIN across a couple tables.

Lots of people have written lots of queries already, so the queries you want might be there -- try searching.

As one starting point, [this list of queries compiled by the Worldbuilding community](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2014/28) has a lot of interesting "site health" queries.  Some of what you're looking for might be there.

You can change the site that a query runs against using a control below the query code:

[image: screen shot]